# PySpark: retrieve mean and the count of values around the mean for groups within a dataframe

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

My raw data comes in a tabular format. It contains observations from different variables. Each observation with the variable name, the timestamp and the value at that time.

> Variable [string], Time [datetime], Value [float]

The data is stored as Parquet in HDFS and loaded into a Spark Dataframe (df). From that dataframe.

Now I want to calculate default statistics like Mean, Standard Deviation and others for each variable. Afterwards, once the Mean has been retrieved, I want to filter/count those values for that variable that are closely around the Mean.

Therefore I need to get the mean for each variable first. This is why I'm using GroupBy to get the statistics for each variable (not for the whole dataset).

```
df_stats = df.groupBy(df.Variable).agg( \
    count(df.Variable).alias("count"), \
    mean(df.Value).alias("mean"), \
    stddev(df.Value).alias("std_deviation"))
```

With the Mean for each variable I then can filter those values (just the count) for that specific variable that are around the Mean. Therefore I need all observations (values) for that variable. Those values are in the original dataframe **df** and not in the aggregated/grouped dataframe **df_stats**.

[image: creating statistics]

Finally I want one dataframe like the aggregated/grouped **df_stats** with a new column **"count_around_mean"**.

I was thinking to use df_stats.map(...) or df_stats.join(df, df.Variable). But I'm stuck on the red arrows :(

**Question:** How would you realize that?

**Temporary Solution:** Meanwhile I'm using a solution that is based on your idea. But the range-functions for stddev range 2 and 3 does not work. It always yields an

> AttributeError saying NullType has no _jvm

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

w1 = Window().partitionBy("Variable")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("Variable").orderBy("Time")

def stddev_pop_w(col, w):
    #Built-in stddev doesn't support windowing
    return sqrt(avg(col * col).over(w) - pow(avg(col).over(w), 2))

def isInRange(value, mean, stddev, radius):
    try:
        if (abs(value - mean) < radius * stddev):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    except AttributeError:
        return -1

delta = col("Time").cast("long") - lag("Time", 1).over(w2).cast("long")
#f = udf(lambda (value, mean, stddev, radius): abs(value - mean) < radius * stddev, IntegerType())
f2 = udf(lambda value, mean, stddev: isInRange(value, mean, stddev, 2), IntegerType())
f3 = udf(lambda value, mean, stddev: isInRange(value, mean, stddev, 3), IntegerType())

df \
    .withColumn("mean", mean("Value").over(w1)) \
    .withColumn("std_deviation", stddev_pop_w(col("Value"), w1)) \
    .withColumn("delta", delta)
    .withColumn("stddev_2", f2("Value", "mean", "std_deviation")) \
    .withColumn("stddev_3", f3("Value", "mean", "std_deviation")) \
    .show(5, False)

#df2.withColumn("std_dev_3", stddev_range(col("Value"), w1)) \
```

Comment: At least for me it is not clear what your really want here. What do you mean by _full time series_? What kind of function you want to apply?

Comment: I reformulated the original question for better understanding. Meanwhile I found a good approach that I need to test tomorrow. I then will upload the idea here as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spark 2.0+**:

You can replace `stddev_pop_w` with one of the built-in `pyspark.sql.functions.stddev*` functions.

**Spark < 2.0**:

In general there is no need for aggregation with join. Instead you can compute statistics without collapsing the rows using window functions. Assuming your data looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean

n = 10000
k = 20

np.random.seed(100)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
    "id": np.arange(n),
    "variable": np.random.choice(k, n),
    "value": np.random.normal(0,  1, n)
}))
```

You can define window with partitioning by `variable`:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().partitionBy("variable")
```

and compute statistics as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, pow, sqrt

def stddev_pop_w(col, w):
    """Builtin stddev doesn't support windowing
    You can easily implement sample variant as well
    """
    return sqrt(avg(col * col).over(w) - pow(avg(col).over(w), 2))


(df
    .withColumn("stddev", stddev_pop_w(col("value"), w))
    .withColumn("mean", avg("value").over(w))
    .show(5, False))

## +---+--------------------+--------+------------------+--------------------+
## |id |value               |variable|stddev            |mean                |
## +---+--------------------+--------+------------------+--------------------+
## |47 |0.77212446947439    |0       |1.0103781346123295|0.035316745261099715|
## |60 |-0.931463439483327  |0       |1.0103781346123295|0.035316745261099715|
## |86 |1.0199074337552294  |0       |1.0103781346123295|0.035316745261099715|
## |121|-1.619408643898953  |0       |1.0103781346123295|0.035316745261099715|
## |145|-0.16065930935765935|0       |1.0103781346123295|0.035316745261099715|
## +---+--------------------+--------+------------------+--------------------+
## only showing top 5 rows
```

Just for comparison aggregate with join:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import stddev, avg, broadcast

df.join(
    broadcast(df.groupBy("variable").agg(avg("value"), stddev("value"))),
    ["variable"]
)
```

Comment: Nice and smart answer as always. Thanks! I will try that tomorrow. I was also thinking to use the Window function to get the time delta between two rows (lag) and also to indicate if q row belongs into a reasonable range around the mean.

Comment: I'm just wondering if calling withColumn/window two times right after is efficient? You could use groupBy/mapValues/StatCounter to get those values in one step. the resulting table is condensed (grouped) but could be merged into the original one.

Comment: Number of times you call withColumn doesn't affect execution plan. If you don't like window functions you may prefer aggregate and join. Regarding passing through RDD this means multiple safe unsafe conversions and heavy IO + serde.

Comment: Works nicely, but if I then want to add another column that is referencing the others that have been just created, then I get AttributeError that somehow refer to NullType.jvm. I updated the code in my original post above. Maybe you have an idea? I'm just trying to set 0 or 1 to those values that are in range 2 or 3 around the mean.

Comment: Remember that when you use UDF you have to manually handle null values. Not to mention Python UDFs are not the first choice performance wise and are not really required or useful here.

Comment: I tried to expain it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227007/pyspark-retrieve-mean-and-the-count-of-values-around-the-mean-for-groups-within/38246827?noredirect=1#comment63953947_38246827).

Comment: Also you really shouldn't `import *` unless you know what you're doing. You shadow built-in `abs` with SQL one.